# Following credit draws on revolving frame

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate:

1.) the amount of new volume

2.) the amount of disposable money (free_volume) after each draw

The returns are not displayed because they are irrelevant in this manner. New volume kicks in only if there is a higher frame volume achieved. The frame starts with client withdrawing the full amount of 100 000. Then he draws another 30K but it is on the same frame level (frame_volume) so the new volume equals zero. Then we have a raise to 150K and the client immediately draws 60 000 - the new volume is 50 000 and free volume is zero because he draw all from the new volume. On 2013-07-23 we have another raise of the frame volume, but this time, the credit is less then new available 50K, so we have a free volume of 24 596, which is lowered in the next withdraw to 1 684. Of course, when the frame drops, f.i. from 280 000 to 150 000, no new volume can be achieved.

Is it possible to somehow calculate the fields new_volume and free_volume?

based on the flow of withdraws.

```
date          frame_volume   credit_draw   new_volume    free_volume
2008-11-06    100 000        100 000       100 000                 0
2009-11-18    100 000         30 000             0                 0    
2012-03-13    150 000         60 000        50 000                 0
2012-06-29    150 000         70 000             0                 0   
2013-06-13    150 000         18 174             0                 0
2013-06-20    150 000         28 669             0                 0
2013-07-23    200 000         25 405        25 405            24 596
2013-09-23    200 000         22 912        22 912             1 684
2013-09-25    200 000         29 316         1 684                 0
2015-04-28    200 000         52 519             0                 0
2015-12-09    200 000         43 004             0                 0
2015-12-15    200 000         29 624             0                 0
2016-01-20    260 000         15 909        15 909            44 091
2016-01-25    260 000         17 162        17 162            26 929
2016-02-10    260 000         95 130        26 929                 0
2016-05-25    260 000         21 862             0                 0
2016-07-11    280 000          9 738         9 738            10 262
2016-08-03    280 000         12 969        10 262                 0
2016-09-26    150 000         40 055             0                 0
2016-11-21    150 000          9 984             0                 0
```

Comment: Which DBMS? mysql <> sql server. What are you expecting as output? And what are you using to define order?

Comment: DBMS is T-SQL (MS SQL 2012) I want to calculate the two last fields (new_volume and free_volume) - i only did this table as an expected result. The first three fields are the actual table. The order is defined according to the credit draw date - from oldest to newest.

Comment: I've tried using the LAG Method to look into previous row so I can tell if there is any difference between frame_volume. So I managed to calculate the new_volume but only when the no new free_volume is generated which can be used in the next withdraw (like the one in the rows 7,8).

Comment: can you give your desired result

Comment: Michael.. The desired result are the two last columns.